# AWS S3 Upload Failure encountered an exception couldn't retry in Android

Tags: android, exception, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-image

I am making an android app in which i take images with camera. Pass the uri of images to upload them to Amazon S3.

At first i had the

> > ERROR:
> >
> > > " The Bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint".

Then I added

> s3Client.setEndpoint( "https://s3.amazonaws.com" );

my region was set as

> s3Client.setRegion( Region.getRegion( Regions.US_EAST_1 ) );

Now I am getting

> **Upload Failure:**
>
> > Encountered an exception and couldn't reset the stream to retry

On browsing I came to know the exception is due to **resetRequestAfterError**

But what is that resetRequestAfterError and why is it happening I have no idea

Could some one help me solve this.

Thanks